# I need to display a column chart where it should have two colours[Amcharts]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amcharts

I need to display two colours in the single column , assume if the value is 50 then till 20 the colour should be green and anything above 20 then it should display with orange colour.

So every column will have 2 colours . If the value is 25 then till 20 the colour is blue and remaining 5 part will be displayed in orange

Comment: Did you have a question for us?

Comment: Good. What are you waiting for !!. Go ahead and implement. Post if you encounter any issues.